# jquery plugin - calling methods

Tags: jquery, plugins, this, self

so I am building my first plugin for jquery I have an init method

```
init: function(options, elem) {
var self = this;
```

This calls a couple of methods
    this.slide(elem);
    this.lightbox(elem);

however in the lightbox method I try and call my custom method  setpositon using

self.setposition(); //error Object [object Window] has no method 'setposition'

or

this.setposition() // Object # has no method 'setposition'

how do I refer to the object I created?

Comment: Could you create a jsFiddle please?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var myObj = {
>      init: function(){
>          var self = this;
>          this.alert();
>          myObj.alert();
>          self.alert();
>      },
>      alert: function(){
>          alert('Im called!');
>      } 
>  };
> ```
>
> myObj.init();​

See it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shehovn/AWfzc/1/).